# Evaluating Root forms in a Table

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, list-manipulation

When I put a Root form in table, the parameters of the Root form don't evaluate. I don't know how I can indexed values substituted into root form in the table to get have numeric output.

```
Table[
  {t, ω, Ω, 
    Root[
      (3.35976*10^-10 t ω Ω Cos[t Ω] Sin[t ω])/(ω^2 - Ω^2)^2 - 
        (3.35976*10^-10 t ω Ω Cos[t ω] Cos[t Ω]^2 Sin[t ω])/(ω^2 - Ω^2)^2 - 
        (3.35976*10^-10 t ω^2 Cos[t ω] Sin[t Ω])/(ω^2 - Ω^2)^2 + 
        (3.35976*10^-10 t ω^2 Cos[t ω]^2 Cos[t Ω] Sin[t Ω])/(ω^2 - Ω^2)^2 - 
        (3.35976*10^-10 t Ω^2 Cos[t Ω] Sin[t ω]^2 Sin[t Ω])/(ω^2 - Ω^2)^2 + 
        (3.35976*10^-10 t ω Ω Cos[t ω] Sin[t ω] Sin[t Ω]^2)/(ω^2 - Ω^2)^2 +    
        (-1.97568*10^-9 t^2 - (7.11809*10^-6 ω^2)/(ω^2 - Ω^2)^2 + 
        (0.0000142362 ω^2 Cos[t ω] Cos[t Ω])/(ω^2 - Ω^2)^2 - 
        (7.11809*10^-6 ω^2 Cos[t ω]^2 Cos[t Ω]^2)/(ω^2 - Ω^2)^2 - 
        (6.88289*10^-6 Ω^2 Cos[t Ω]^2 Sin[t ω]^2)/(ω^2 - Ω^2)^2 + 
        (0.0000142362 ω Ω Sin[t ω] Sin[t Ω])/(ω^2 - Ω^2)^2 - 
        (4.704*10^-7 ω Ω Cos[t ω] Cos[t Ω] Sin[t ω] Sin[t Ω])/(ω^2 - Ω^2)^2 -
        (6.88289*10^-6 ω^2 Cos[t ω]^2 Sin[t Ω]^2)/(ω^2 - Ω^2)^2 - 
        (7.11809*10^-6 Ω^2 Sin[t ω]^2 Sin[t Ω]^2)/(ω^2 - Ω^2)^2) #1 + #1^3 &, 
      1]}, 
  {ω, 0, π, 2 π/10}, {Ω, 0, π, 2 π/10}, {t, 0, 0.5, 0.1}]
```

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are having is caused by the index specifications `{ω, 0, π, 2 π/10}`, and `{Ω, 0, π, 2 π/10}` producing singularities. With your indexing, the expression `(ω^2 - Ω^2)^2` appearing in the denominator of certain terms of the Root form expression is often zero.

There is no problem if the table is indexed over values of `ω` and `Ω` that do not make `(ω^2 - Ω^2)^2` zero.

Comment: thanks for your answer, But I have many other equations in Table as a vector and I can't  put a condition in table. I just have a problem with Root equations and know I don't know how can I solve it.

Comment: @Some. Try phase-shifting one of `ω` or `Ω` by some quantity, say `π/10`, so that `(ω^2 - Ω^2)^2` will not be zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot m_Goldberg, by using your useful answer and comment, the program is running now.